# When did Toad get a flaming tongue?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men

So, I was on the Internet earlier, and as I was browsing through some X-Men sites, I read that apparently Toad has developed a new mutation where he can now engulf his tongue in flames. *So*... can somebody explain when this happened? I'm a little behind on the X-Men books, but didn't realize they were making such... *unique* changes.

Comment: Fire power that allows him to kick more butt, hardly *that* unique a mutation in the Marvel universe.  Now, if Toad suddenly developed a killer talent for creative writing, that would be something.

Comment: I thought that my answer was pretty comprehensive, showing both the first mention of his new powers and their genesis. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum-Actually, it looks pretty good as is. I just read the first six issues of X-Men Blue in Volume 1: Strangest, now just waiting on Volume 2, so I'm looking forward to seeing how the new power works into the story as a whole.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [X-Men: Blue #7](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Men:_Blue_Vol_1_7), Toad's tongue is now capable of setting things on fire. No further explanation is given other than that as he matured, he developed a [secondary mutation](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Secondary_Mutation).

[image]